# failed at update a global variable passed by context processor in Flask

Tags: python, flask

How can I update the global variable in flask passed by context processor?
I tried the following in index.html, it works for index.html, but it fails for other html files.

//(1)inside index.html

```
{% set user = [3,4] %}
{{user}}
```

//(2)inside **init**.py

```
val = [1,2]

@app.context_processor

def inject_user():

    return dict(user=val)
```

//(3)inside layout.html

```
{{ user }}
```

So I refresh the webpage, I expect to see the layout.html will print [3,4], however, it still print [1,2].
Any idea about how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is index.html your base template?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

layout.html is the base. and index.html extends it.

Comment: index.html extends layout.html. layout.html is parent to index.html. So, what you set in index will not be set in layout. If you set [3.4] in layout, then only layout will print [3,4].